# Flex4.6 : works in debug but not in Release build

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

My flex4.6 works normally in debug.
But when I create a release version, I got:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

at com.adobe.serializers.utility::TypeUtility$/getArrayType()
at com.adobe.serializers.json::JSONDecoder/parseObject()
at com.adobe.serializers.json::JSONDecoder/parseValue()
at com.adobe.serializers.json::JSONDecoder/decode()
at com.bravolucy.football.utilities::Utilities$/getAsObj()

looks like:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4250338

Original project was done in flex4.0 and it uses some swc libraries.

Comment: do I need to precise that the question is: "how to solve that ?" or "how to avoid that error ?"

Comment: that was a bit obnoxious of me - my apologies; been reading too many poorly asked questions recently and i guess its made me a bit temperamental

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of your question is in your question itself

> "Original project was done in flex4.0 and it uses some swc libraries"

before this para it was said

> flex4.6 works normally in debug

It should be working fine with 4.6 because with this version playerglobal.version 11.1 being used normally which has JSON lib included with it but prior version to playerglobal - 11 you need to include "[as3corelib.swc](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)" in your project libs.

More details you can find at - http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/working-with-native-json-in-flash-player-11/

Thanks,

Varun

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and tick as3corelib.swc in project properties.

But even better would be to switch to native `JSON.parse`